# Sum over Permutations and Possible Relations with the Polya Enumeration Theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics

A specialization of the Polya enumeration theorem can give rise to the following identity:

$\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{\pi \in S_k} n^{cyc(\pi)} = {n+k-1 \choose k}, $

where $S_k$ is the permutation group of degree $k$ and $cyc(\pi)$ is the number of cycles in the permutation $\pi$. Now, I am interested in the following summation

$\sum_{\pi \in S_k} n_1^{cyc(\pi)} n_2^{cyc(\pi \xi )} n_3^{cyc(\pi \xi^{-1})}, $

where $\xi$ is the cyclic permutation of the cycle type $(123....k)$. **Is there an expression in closed form for this summation just like the previous summation? Is this summation related to the Polya enumeration theorem in some way？** We might need to separately discuss the two cases with even $k$ and odd $k$. The naive reasoning is that, for example, if we look at the term with the highest power in, say $n_2$, we get $n_1n_2^k n_3$ for odd $k$ and $n_1n_2^k n_3^2$ for even $k$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but stated here for lack of margins in the "comments" area.

First, I do not believe there will be a nice structural description for the sum, let alone a closed form. A couple of things are apparent:

(a) the sum is symmetric in $n_2$ and $n_3$ but not in $n_1$;

(b) while from above, 
$$\sum_{\pi\in S_k}x^{cyc(\pi)}=(x)^{(k)}.$$
Here is a contrasting analogue
$$-\sum_{\pi\in S_k}x^{cyc(\pi)}(-1)^{cyc(\pi\xi)}=(x)_{(k)}.$$

**Notations.** $(x)^{(k)}$ and $(x)_{(k)}$ stand for rising and falling factorials, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am quite curious about the second identity you wrote here. Could you please explain a bit how to derive it?

Comment: If $k$ is odd and $\pi\in S_k$ then $cyc(\pi)$ and $cyc(\pi\xi)$ have the same parity. If $k$ is even and $\pi\in S_k$ then $cyc(\pi)$ and $cyc(\pi\xi)$ have opposite parity.